# Angular/Ionic Chat example?

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to do the same example in the default Ionic template (tabs). Where you have a tab called **chat** that holds a bunch of pictures with descriptions and when you click on one of these items in the list you will get more details. and that all was done using a pre-defined array (hard coded).

In my case I am trying to do the same but with a json array that holds values coming from a remote database. I am defining a **factory** in service.js file to do so. However, because I am calling an async request using the **$http**, the returned json array won't hold the values immediately (it needs time) and that causes that the returned array from the factory to be empty.

My factory is like the following:

```
.factory('GCs', ['$http', function($http) {
    // this is the var that I want to pass to get method
    //but it will be empty because the get method in the return section will be executed before the call finished.
    var obj = {};

    $http.post("mydomina.com?myrequest=getbyid", {
            "id": "1"
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            obj = data; //there is a data returned correctly from the db
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //TODO something..
        });

    console.log(obj); //obj is undefined?

    return {
        all: function() {
            return obj; //obj is empty here!!
        },
        get: function(gcId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < gcs.length; i++) {
                if (gcs[i].id === parseInt(gcId)) {
                    return gcs[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then in the controller file, I have my own controller that calls this factory for the all/get method like the following.

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, GCs) {
    console.log(GCs.all());// it is giving me undefined 
    $scope.GCResult = GCs.all(); //GCResult is empty and thereby no data will be displayed when I pass the scope to the view.
})

.controller('GCDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, GCs) {
    $scope.item = GCs.get($stateParams.GC_ID);
})
```

I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the promise that `$http.post()` produces ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http))

```
.factory('GCs', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            getById: function(id) {
              return $http.post("mydomina.com?myrequest=getbyid", { "id": id });
            }
        };
}]);
```

and change your controller to

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, GCs) {

    $scope.getData = function(id){
        GCs.getData(id)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.GCResult = data; 
            });
    };
})
```

and it should be working fine

Comment: You are right!! now how to solve the second part of the issue where each item in the item list has its own details. Look at the changes that I made on my question. Basically I want to use the get method in the return section and thereby form the ID I can display the details of the clicked item

Comment: edited. the idea is that you call the `getData(id)` from your html code (the id is the matching id of the current iterated item)

Comment: hmm.. could you please explain more? it seems logic and that is what I am trying to do.. The screen that calls GCDetailCtrl is nested logically under the screen that calls DashCtrl and thereby getting the ID of the clicked element can fetch the details of that element. 

so It's 2 functions getAll (to bring all the items) and on the click I call getbyID(id) to bring the details of that item

Comment: I need to have 2 separate screens like the Chat example

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/82309/angular-ionic-chat-example?tab=general

Comment: No I mean the tab example -> chat section

Comment: **click [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82309/angular-ionic-chat-example)**, let's continue this in the chat

Answer (score 0):

The promise returned from `$http` cannot be bound directly:

```
.factory('GCs', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      return $http.post("mydomina.com?myrequest=getbyid", { "id": "1"} );
    }
  };
}]);
```

In Angular 1.2 auto-unwrapping of promises was removed. See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises.

Comment: I tried that method. it did not work, and it did not give me an error at the same time. 
I need the data out of this async request